# Dojo: Iterate through chained animations?

Tags: javascript, dojo, loops

I have a simple animation built with the Dojo animation class that displays five hidden list items in ten second increments. Here's an example:

dojo.fx.chain ([

dojo.animateProperty({
    node:progressList[0],
    duration:listItemDuration,
    onEnd:function(){
        dojo.style(this.node, 'display', 'block');
        }
    }),

...

dojo.animateProperty({
    node:progressList[5],
    duration:listItemDuration,
    onEnd:function(){
        dojo.style(this.node, 'display', 'block');
        }
    })
]).play();

Listing these properties individually is cumbersome. It makes more sense to iterate through a single dojo.animateProperty.

Is it possible to iterate through elements in dojo.fx.chain, using dojo.forEach or some other method?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely.

Something like:

```
    var hiddenNodes = dojo.query('.hidden');
    var anims = [];
    hiddenNodes.forEach(function(n) {
        anims.push(dojo.animateProperty({
            node: n,
            properties: {
                color: 'red'
            },
            duration: 1000
        }));
    });

    var finalAnim = dojo.fx.chain(anims);
```

Note, we only create this once. Afterwards `finalAnim` can be passed around and have `play()` called on it at will.